# Rails を用いてデータベース内を確認した後の終了の処理を間違えてしまいました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Ruby on Railsの勉強をしていて、 "select * form posts” としてデータベース内を覗いていました。その後、".quit"と入力をして終了させないといけないのに、"quit"と入力を間違えてしまいました。
`[sqlite>` という表示が `[  ...>` と変わってしまい、改めて .quit を入力しても終了されません。
どのようにすれば終了させられるのでしょうか。

[image: .quit と入力しないといけないのに quit と誤入力してしまった]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セミコロンを入れると文の区切りとして認識され、SQLiteが実行しようとしてエラーを出します。すると同時に、プロンプトが元に戻ります。

```
sqlite> quit
...> ???
...> ;
Error: near "quit": syntax error
sqlite> .quit
(終了する)
```